# Facebook Graph API returns question mark picture, post picture is visible on post page directly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I am working on Facebook Canvas application.
Application purpose is to access to user's accounts, collect posts and preview them posts are photo type.

It also allows same user to see other user's posts.

If user is looking other users' posts, preview on some of posts is question mark picture instead of image in post. If user opens post directly to post Facebook page, picture is visible.

I am using Graph API to retrieve pictures from posts for preview.
Current syntax is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<OBJECT_ID>/picture?type=normal&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

I tried to use page access token as well long living user access token.
In both cases I got question mark picture.

My questions are:

1. Why is it not possible to see real image through application when user gave permissions to pictures?
2. Is it possible to detect if image is question mark picture?

**EDIT**
I use OBJECT_ID, not post ID. Preview is for photo posts. object_id in post is picture id, which can be used in pictures Graph API.

**EDIT 2**
Only Graph API must be used, nothing else.

**EDIT 3**
These are permissions that are requested from user: "email", "user_photos", "manage_pages", "read_stream", "read_insights", "user_hometown", "user_location", "user_birthday".

Comment: As for your second question: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

Comment: @CBroe I saw is_silhouette tag for using JSON response, but that is not problem since I know there is picture, and as in regular facebook post page I can see it. 
Both questions are in context and related.

Answer (score 0):

get needed permissions (user_photos & friends_photos)
if you want to get users pics(or friends) try fql its much better in my opinion

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

or graph api & dont forget to get needed permissions

here are two fql examples

```
SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND modified_major > 1349374365) ORDER BY created DESC

SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1= 100001785452297 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,20 ) ORDER BY created DESC
```

at last i recommend you to use facebook sdk for your programming language

Comment: My solution works for objects. If you see, there is <OBJECT_ID> and like I said, it works for all posts except specific ones. 
This means that object ID is needed, not post ID.

Comment: Also, FQL usage is not option to use. Only Graph API.

Comment: Another thing, do you know needed permissions? I updated what we require in original question.

Comment: how is friends_photos related to pages user administer?

Comment: Problem is not user photos or user friends photos. Problem is with user pages posts photo. Please take into consideration that I will not use FQL. 
All solutions with FQL should be avoid.

Comment: you want to get photos from pages user is admin of them ?

Comment: & fql is not an independent way to get information its accessible  via graph api

Comment: downvote is not a good way to thank someone is trying to help you:D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38877/discussion-between-entersb-and-pooya-estakhri)